# Does the Acer E5 support Sata3?

Tags: laptop, ssd, sata, acer-aspire

I am considering getting an SSD for my Acer E5 machine.  Looking at the machine's specs, I can't figure out if it has SATA3 and will support fast SSD speeds.  The machine is a E5-573-55W1.  Here are the [full specs for Acer](http://www.acer.ca/ac/en/CA/content/model/NX.MVHAA.006).

I have already pulled out the old drive, but I could put it back in if there is a Windows or Linux software check that I can do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the bottom of the web page that you linked, the computer does support USB 3.0. That would imply a SATA 3 system drive would work, also. Just make sure your new SSD is SATA 3, and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

That chip's [a broadwell](http://ark.intel.com/products/85212/Intel-Core-i5-5200U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_70-GHz) and the chipsets for anything sandy bridge or later would support sata 3. Chances are most common SSDs should fit in the space of the current hard drive - its worth double checking its a 7mm drive, but *electrically* you should be golden.